# About SSL Certificate in Production. Why doesn't my request work?

Tags: java, node.js, angular, typescript, http

I have a `get (http)` request in my Java code, in localhost I can run normally, my code works, but in production I get no response. Returns error `500`.

When I test my production request by Postman, it returns a message missing `SSL` certificate. My questions are how to solve this problem and is the error possible due to lack of `SSL`?

My production site does not have `SSL` certificate

Comment: What does an SSL certificate have to do with Angular?

Comment: we need more information to answer your question